# for loop inside another for loop javascript (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this select options color:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="selected_color" name="inkColor">
    <option disabled selected>select color:</option>
    <option id="red">Red</option>
    <option id="blue">Blue</option>
    <option id="green">Green</option>
    <option id="black">Black</option>
</select>
```

I want to make a for loop javascript for this 4 lines that used for hide option that have value `<= 0`

**JS:**

```
$('option#red').attr("hidden", true);
$('option#blue').attr("hidden", true);
$('option#green').attr("hidden", true);
$('option#black').attr("hidden", true);
```

I try to make `for` loop for above code.

**JS:**

```
//TO HIDE SELECT COLOR THAT DOSE NOT HAVE A VALUE
//color values
red= -1;
blue=9;
green= -4;
black=3;

//red and green must be hide because it's less than 0 

color_value = [red,blue,green,black];
for(var $x=0 ; $x < color_value.length ; $x++){   //first for loop
    color_str=['red','blue','green','black'];
    for(var $j=0 ; $j < color.length ; $j++){     //second for loop
        ids = "option#"+color[$j];
        if (color_value[$x] <= 0){
            $(ids).attr("hidden", true);
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can see it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qu8ekvhk/)

Comment: Here's the thing, you can't reliably hide option elements cross-browser, so you might as well give up. You have to actually remove the options from the DOM.

Comment: Do you set values in JS as I don't see values in your markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confused indexes variables, it should be `color_value[$j]`:

```
for(var $x=0 ; $x < color_value.length ; $x++){   //first for loop
    for(var $j=0 ; $j < color_str.length ; $j++){     //second for loop
        ids = "option#"+color_str[$j];
        if (color_value[$j] <= 0){
            $(ids).attr("hidden", true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/qu8ekvhk/3/

One more simpler option with alternative (more convenient) data structure:

```
var colors = {
    red: -1,
    blue: 9,
    green: -4,
    black: 3
};

$('#selected_color option').filter(function() {
    return colors[this.id] < 0;
}).hide();
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/qu8ekvhk/1/

Also, as pointed in comments if you support IE, then you can't just hide option in this browser, you will have to either `remove()` them or use one of the many workarounds.

Comment: try it in IE, `hide()` will fail...not supported

Comment: Hm, interesting, didn't know it about. Let me check.

Comment: will also fail in safari I believe

Comment: thanks for help :) . About IE if I use for loop ( first demo ) , Is IE support it or not.

Comment: No. The problem is that IE can't hide option element in select. So you can delete option instead `$(ids).remove();`.

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing `color.length` and `color[$j]` when you don't have this defined (at least not in the code you showed us). Did you mean to use `color_str`?

```
...

for(var $x=0 ; $x < color_value.length ; $x++)   //first for loop
{  
    color_str=['red','blue','green','black'];
    for(var $j=0 ; $j < color_str.length ; $j++)     //second for loop
    {
        ids = "option#"+color_str[$j];

        if (color_value[$x] <= 0)
        {
            $(ids).attr("hidden", true);
        }
    }
 }
```

This code also isn't doing what (I think) you're trying to achieve, as the second loop is only checking the current value of `$x`, so will end up hiding *all* elements if the condition is met, not just the correct option.

Something like this is preferable:

```
var red   = -1,
    blue  = 9,
    green = -4,
    black = 3;

var color_value = [red, blue, green, black];
var color_str = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black'];

for (var $x = 0; $x < color_value.length; $x ++)
{
    var id = "option#" + color_str[$x];

    if (color_value[$x] <= 0) {
        $(id).hide();
    }
}
```

As [@dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28813783/1794631) has already mentioned, it'd be much better to use objects for this, as the colour and its value are related pieces of data. Unless you have a good reason for doing so, using 2 separate arrays to hold the data is not ideal.

Comment: what do you expect `attr('hidden')` to do? Can't hide option tag cross browser and `hidden` doesn't do anything anyway